# Using multiprocessing and ProcessPoolExecutor simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, deadlock, process-pool

I am trying to create a simple script for python3.5 that can execute heavy computer vision algorithms in parallel. I have created a process by **multiprocessing.Process** in main process.
Inside that process I create **concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor**. Spawned process submits tasks to **processPoolExecutor** and it works perfectly fine. But when I try to stop and join spawned process it hangs on join.

Also if replace processPoolExecuter to threadPoolExecuter everything works perfectly. What did I miss?

**Here is main file:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue as Queue
import numpy as np
import cv2
from time import sleep
import executer_debug

def worker(queue):
    pExecutor = executer_debug.Worker()
    pExecutor.set()

    while True:
        print("-->{}<--".format(pExecutor.get()))
        sleep(1)

        try:
            income = queue.get_nowait()
            break
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        pExecutor.set()

    print("<1>{}<1>".format(pExecutor.get()))
    print("<2>{}<2>".format(pExecutor.get()))

def main():

    queue = mp.Queue()
    currProcess = mp.Process(target = worker, args=(queue,))
    currProcess.start()

    frame = np.zeros((480,640), dtype=np.uint8)

    while True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    print("stopped")
    queue.put("stop")

    currProcess.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the second file. Code is very simple just enough to demonstrate the issue.

```
import collections
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp


def worker():
    return 1

class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers_count = 4
        self.poolExecutor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = self.workers_count)
        self.executors = collections.deque()

    def set(self):
        self.executors.append(self.poolExecutor.submit(worker))

    def get(self):
        if len(self.executors) > 0:
            if self.executors[0].done():
                return self.executors.popleft().result()
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return -1
```

Thank you!